# Why there is no compilation error when static_cast float to int?

Tags: c++

What will happen when you execute this code snippet?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   float a = 5.51;
   int b = static_cast<int>(a);
   std::cout << b;
}
```

Correct answer is:

> 5 will be printed on standard output, with no compilation warnings generated.

But for me would make more sense to generate compilation warning as precision would be lost. Why not?

Comment: The explicit cast tells the compiler you did the conversion intenionally, and therefore there's no need for a warning. Most compiler will issue a warning if you assign a `float` to an `int` **without** a cast.

Comment: If you do a direct assignment with implicit conversion (i.e. `int b = a;`) then most compilers should give a warning (at least if you enable more warnings, which is always a good idea). But `static_cast<int>(a)` is an *explicit* conversion, that makes the compiler think you made it intentionally and that you really know what you're doing.

Comment: You order a pizza. And when the Waiter arrives, you **explicitly** tell him he should make a Pizza shake instead.
After the waiter comes back with a Pizza shake, you complain you weren't warned that your pizza becomes a pizza shake.

Comment: The whole point of the cast is to lose precision without a nitpicking compiler pestering you about it.

Comment: `float a = 5.51;` loses precision (double converted to float).  `int b = static_cast<int>(a);` explicitly tells the compiler to lose precision.  You could make your own conversion routine that can throw an exception if the conversion would lose precision that you care about.

Comment: @Eljay -- `5.51` loses precision, too: text converted to double! But that's a rathole...

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on compiler level of warning. In my case with Visual Studio 2022 and level warnings set to lvl 4, I get the following warning:

Warning C4305   'init': truncation from 'double' to 'float'.

Comment: That warning message is about initializing the `float` variable `a` using the `double` value `5.51`. Not about the conversion of the `float` value inside the variable `a` to an `int` value for the initialization of the variable `b`.

Comment: Same for clang with `-Wimplicit-float-conversion` enabled. But I think both OP and the author of the quiz are referring to the `static_cast` which should not generate a warning.

Comment: @perivesta think in my workplace environment it was set to enabled and tricked me on this question.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @wohlstad:

> The explicit cast tells the compiler you did the conversion
> intenionally, and therefore there's no need for a warning. Most
> compiler will issue a warning if you assign a float to an `int`
> **without** a cast.